# Have a dataframe restart it's count for a particular column

Tags: python, pandas

### The Overview:

In our project, we are working with a CSV file that contains some data. We will call it [smal.csv](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/tisaconundrum2/ee85d5a3f28fbaf5cf64073823a8aa84/raw/eb7d0f3eb68638dd9023d832fda3fdc0eea43a42/smal.tsv) It is a bit of a chunky file that will be later used for some other algorithms. (Here is the [gist](https://gist.github.com/tisaconundrum2/ee85d5a3f28fbaf5cf64073823a8aa84) in case the link to smal.csv is too badly formatted for your browser.)

The file will be loaded like this

```
filename = "smal.csv"
keyname = "someKeyname"
self.data[keyname] = spectral_data(pd.read_csv(filename, header=[0, 1], verbose=True))
```

---

The spectral class looks like this. As you can see, we do not actually keep the dataframe as is.

```
class spectral_data(object):
    def __init__(self, df):

        try:
            uppercols = df.columns.levels[0]
            lowercols = list(df.columns.levels[1].values)
        except:
            df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(list(df.columns))
            uppercols = df.columns.levels[0]
            lowercols = list(df.columns.levels[1].values)

        for i, val in enumerate(lowercols):
            try:
                lowercols[i] = float(val)
            except:
                lowercols[i] = val

        levels = [uppercols, lowercols]
        df.columns.set_levels(levels, inplace=True)
        self.df = df
```

---

After we've loaded it we'd like to concatenate it with another set of data, also loaded like `smal.csv` was.

Our concatenation is done like this.

```
new_df = pd.concat([self.data[dataSet1].df, self.data[dataSet2].df], ignore_index=True)
```

However, the `ignore_index=True` does not work, because the actual row that we are concatenating is not the index. However, we cannot simply remove the column, it is necessary for other parts of our program.

### The Objective:

I'm trying to concatenate a couple of data frames together, however, what I thought was the index is not actually the index for the data frame. Thus the command

```
pd.concat([df1.df, df2.df], ignore_index=True)
```

will not work. I thought maybe using `iloc` to change each individual cell would work but I feel like this is not the most intuitive way to approach this.

---

How can I get a data frame that looks like this

```
[396 rows x 6207 columns]
    Unnamed: 0_level_0                        meta  ...       wvl       
    Unnamed: 0_level_1                      Sample  ...   932.695 932.89
0                    1                         NaN  ...    -12.33   9.67
1                    2                         NaN  ...     11.94   3.94
2                    3                         NaN  ...     -2.67  28.33
3                    4                         NaN  ...     53.22 -13.78
4                    1                         NaN  ...     43.28   
5                    2                         NaN  ...     41.33  47.33
6                    3                         NaN  ...    -21.94  12.06
7                    4                         NaN  ...    -30.94  -1.94
8                    5                         NaN  ...    -24.78  40.22
```

Turn into this.

```
[396 rows x 6207 columns]
    Unnamed: 0_level_0                        meta  ...       wvl       
    Unnamed: 0_level_1                      Sample  ...   932.695 932.89
0                    1                         NaN  ...    -12.33   9.67
1                    2                         NaN  ...     11.94   3.94
2                    3                         NaN  ...     -2.67  28.33
3                    4                         NaN  ...     53.22 -13.78
4                    5                         NaN  ...     43.28   
5                    6                         NaN  ...     41.33  47.33
6                    7                         NaN  ...    -21.94  12.06
7                    8                         NaN  ...    -30.94  -1.94
8                    9                         NaN  ...    -24.78  40.22
```

[image]

Comment: From what i understood, you have a multi level index and need to reset all values in second column of index, right?

Comment: @Greesha0 Yes, that's right

Comment: What about dropping second column of index? `df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True)`

Comment: Let me give that a shot

Comment: That solved your problem?

Comment: No it did it not

Comment: Try something like this: `df.reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index().set_index(['index', np.arange(1, 1+len(df))])`. Also, `pd.concat([df1.df, df2.df], ignore_index=True)` throws some exception?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/167209/discussion-between-tisaconundrum-and-greesha0).